# Strange C++ syntax error with '('

Tags: c++, class, syntax, header, typedef

I'm having a strange issue with my code (or perhaps I'm just a bit rusty): The following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

typedef vector<double> vDouble;
typedef vector<int> vInt;

//Class for calculations
class CallCosts
{
    CallCosts::CallCosts();
    CallCosts::CallCosts(vDouble nrates(4, 0)); //Constructor

    void CallCosts::setRates(vDouble sr(4, 0));
    void CallCosts::getTotals(vDouble gt(4, 0), vInt minutes(4, 0));

    vDouble rates(4, 0);
    vDouble totals(4, 0);

};
```

The compiler gives me an error on line 16:

```
CallCosts::CallCosts(vDouble nrates(4, 0)); //Constructor
```

The error is: expected ',' or '...' before '(' token.

Now I'm pretty sure I haven't missed a ; anywhere, so what else could be causing this? Another note: I was using plain variables instead of the typedefs previously, and the code worked, so that's probably the issue, but further than that I'm not sure?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please consider reading at least some basic book on C++.

Comment: This isn't just slightly off, so it is hard to help.  You cannot initialise the nrate parameter like that.  Perhaps you can clarify what you were wanting that line to mean?

Comment: What's the meaning of '(4, 0)' everywhere?

Comment: I'm using vector to create arrays, and the (4, 0) is to set the size - I'm assuming I'm doing it wrong? Do I need to build the size call into the typedef? Without the typedef, it would look like:

vector<double> nrates(4, 0)

Comment: And all your members will be private too.

Comment: if there is some better way to achieve what i'm trying to achieve here, please let me know, it's been a while since I did any coding, so as I said, I'm rusty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `CallCosts::` inside the class declaration.

Also, what is this `CallCosts::CallCosts(vDouble nrates(4, 0));` supposed to mean?

If you want a constructor with parameter of type `vDouble`, use `CallCosts(vDouble nrates)`.
If you want to specify a default value, do this `CallCosts(vDouble nrates= vDouble(4, 0));` and remove the default constructor.

Comment: Okay, but I'm not trying to specify a default value, I'm trying to specify the size of the vector - how would I do that?

Comment: @user1863159 - you can't specify the size. You can check the size using `nrates.size()` inside the function body.

Comment: Okay, I'm just being stupid now, as I can add members to the vector using push_back... Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 3):

Your declaration of the constructor is wrong:

```
 CallCosts::CallCosts(vDouble nrates(4, 0));
```

It should look like this:

```
CallCosts(const vDouble& nrates);
```

You pass your vector by const reference.

The definition should look like this:

```
CallCosts::CallCosts(const vDouble& nrates) : rates(nrates) {}
```

Here you're using an initializer list to initialize your private variable with what's passed as an argument to your constructor.

Comment: Alright, I see what you're saying - but how would I specify the length of the vector?

Comment: Nevermind, see below, it's not actually necessary. I'm way too tired for this. Thanks for the response :)